# Why those widgets with layouts don't work

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is a schema for what I want:
[image: This is a schema for what I want]

This is what I try to do. Black line its Window. I want to have a QWidget (red line) that will hold a vertical list of QWidgets. I don't know where I'm making mistake. Does it work differently then what I think?

Here's code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        mainLay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLay)

        # QWidget
        listW = QWidget()
        listW.setStyleSheet('background: lightgreen')
        mainLay.addWidget(listW)
        listLay = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLay.addLayout(listLay)

        row1 = QLabel("1")
        row1.setStyleSheet('background: green')
        listLay.addWidget(row1)

        row2 = QLabel("2")
        row2.setStyleSheet('background: red')
        listLay.addWidget(row2)

        self.resize(400, 300)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, if you want widgets layed out vertically, why are you using a horizontal boxed layout? Also, your first image doesn't match what you're doing in your code anyway: is the light green widget supposed to be the one with the red border of the first image (the "inner container")?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a QHBoxLayout ("H" for horizontal) and adding 2 widgets, and that layout you are placing in the QVBoxLayout ("V" for vertical).

You only need a QVBoxLayout and there place all the widgets:

```py
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        listW = QWidget()
        listW.setStyleSheet("background: lightgreen")

        row1 = QLabel("1")
        row1.setStyleSheet("background: green")

        row2 = QLabel("2")
        row2.setStyleSheet("background: red")

        mainLay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLay.addWidget(listW)
        mainLay.addWidget(row1)
        mainLay.addWidget(row2)

        self.resize(400, 300)
```

If you want to have a container QWidget then add it through another layout:

```py
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        container = QWidget(styleSheet="background: salmon")

        row1 = QLabel("1", styleSheet="background: lightgreen")
        row2 = QLabel("2", styleSheet="background: green")
        row3 = QLabel("3", styleSheet="background: red")

        container_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        container_layout.addWidget(container)

        mainLay = QVBoxLayout(container)
        mainLay.addWidget(row1)
        mainLay.addWidget(row2)
        mainLay.addWidget(row3)

        self.resize(400, 300)
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for a "further" inner widget? (I'm not sure, as, besides the horizontal layout issue, the question is a bit confusing, and it seems that the code doesn't match the provided image: there should be 4 widgets, but only 3 are created).

Comment: @musicamante The same I think, so there are several interpretations, so I opted for the simplest option. If the OP doesn't like my answer then he will have to improve his post to avoid confusion.

Comment: I need the outher QWidget to hold together rows of other qwidgets ( they will have other widgets inside). Outher QWidget is also in bigger gui but for simplicity here I put it iin window. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: thank you for the update :) Is there no need to add new layout to parent? I thought it was necessary to do it.

Comment: Could you point out what I did wrong in my code?

Comment: @dorothy If you want it to be wrong in your code then just compare it to mine